# SWIG Python Crash when redefining function with pointers using inline

Tags: python, c, pointers, inline, swig

I'm relatively new to using SWIG, i'm wrapping a C library in python, and since it's a C library a lot of the functions use pointers to output whatever it is.

The issue that i had was related to a double pointer for example :

```
int function(const char* name, Module** mod)
```

Under C, i would create a Module* and pass its adress to function and the function does whatever, but in python i decided to go another route.
My solution was basically using %inline to redefine function

```
%inline %{
Module* Pyfunction(const char* name){
Module* mod;
function(name, &mod);
return mod;
}
%}
```

And this part seems to be working, Module is a void*, so when checking the module returned it is a void**

```
Module : <Swig Object of type 'void **' at 0x0000027574E52810>
```

Now the i have other functions that are supposed to return a double pointer, and they take Module* as input, for example :

```
int function2(Module* module, DPstruct** s)
```

I do the same thing using the inline trick to return DPstruct with a Pyfunction2, DPstruct is generated correctly as an output and seems to be working, the issue is module becomes corrupted, when i try to output it or use it in another function( that always works if module isn't used as an argument for Pyfunction2 before) the program simply crashes.

I am new to SWIG, I could try to use cpointer.i but I don't want whoever uses my software to start thinking about double pointers and pointers and simply use it like it is python.

Does anyone have any idea why the program crashes when i try to ouput Module* module after passing it to my inline function ?

Thanks.

Comment: A few questions. Is this your entire `.i` file? Does SWIG know about the definitions of `Module` and `DPstruct`? Also, I think you may be facing undefined behavior, but it's hard to tell without the definitions of `function` and `function2`; passing a pointer to a pointer indicates you may actually need the address of the variable passed in; so its lifetime may need to persist beyond the scope of `Pyfunction`. If you could include those definitions it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, no my .i file contains the includes to my headers as well as typemaps.i since i'm outputing any int* that my functions may have as arg, and swig is aware that Module is of type void* as well as DPstruct. The code is confidential which is why i tried to give a general explanation for the functions. I modified the code so that instead of having : DPstruct* s; in the .i i do  DPstruct* s = new DPstruct(); and it seems to be working but i'll have to destroy the object after which i guess i have no choice but to do it. Thanks again

Comment: This is a little too abstract.  Make a [mre] illustrating your implementation using dummy functions that the same signatures but minimal implementation to get it to compile.  You don't need to reveal any confidential code.